# Loop through a recordset (PHP + MySQL) grouping each 2 records in a list item

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I need to loop through a recordset (PHP + MySQL), grouping each 2 records in a list item

My actual code (semplified) is this:

```
<?php
// how many total records do I have?
mysql_select_db($database_connEIB, $connEIB);
$query_rsMediaCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS med_count FROM media";
$rsMediaCount = mysql_query($query_rsMediaCount, $connEIB) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsMediaCount = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMediaCount);

$mCount = $row_rsMediaCount['med_count']; // total records
$mPages = ceil($mCount / 2); // max LIs to create
$mIndex = 0; // useful initialization for LIMIT, see below

if ($mCount > 0) { // let's show markup only if there's some record!
?>
    <ul>
    <?php for ($mPage = 1; $mPage <= $mPages; $mPage++) { // create the LIs ?>
        <li>
        <?php
        $query_rsMedia = "SELECT med_id FROM media LIMIT $mIndex, 2";
        $rsMedia = mysql_query($query_rsMedia, $connEIB) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_rsMedia = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMedia);
        do { ?>
            <div><?php echo $row_rsMedia['med_id']; ?></div>
        <?php } while ($row_rsMedia = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMedia));
        $mIndex += 2; // increment the LIMIT by 2 steps ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

The output is sort like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>5</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Everything works, but is there a more elegant or efficient solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do only one query and group the results within the loop. Use the modulo operator `%`:

```
$query_rsMedia = "SELECT med_id FROM media";
$rsMedia = mysql_query($query_rsMedia, $connEIB) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($rsMedia) > 0) { // check if there is at least one result
    echo '<ul>';
    $index = 0;
    while ($row_rsMedia = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMedia)) {
        if ($index % 2 == 0) echo '<li>'; // open <li> bevore even result
        echo '<div>'.$row_rsMedia['med_id'].'</div>';
        if ($index % 2 == 1) echo '</li>'; // close <li> after odd result
        $index++;
    }
    if ($index % 2 == 1) echo '</li>'; // close <li> if odd result count
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

(just written, not testet)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to run fewer queries.

```
$query_rsMedia = "SELECT med_id FROM media";
$rsMedia = mysql_query($query_rsMedia, $connEIB) or die(mysql_error());
$count = 0;

echo '<ul>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMedia))
{
   //check divisibility to know when to show li
   if ($count % 2 == 0) {
      echo '<li>';          
   } 

   echo '<div>' . $row['med_id'] . '</div>';
   $count++;

   if ($count % 2 == 0) {
      echo '</li>';          
   }
}
if ($count % 2 == 1) echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask query once without the LIMIT statement. Then do something like this:

```
$iteration=0;
echo '<li><ul>';
while ($row_rsMedia = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMedia)
{
    echo '<div>'.$row_rsMedia['med_id'].'</div>';
    $iteration++;
    if ($iteration%2==0 && $iteration<$mCount)
        echo '</ul><ul>'
}
echo '</ul><li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the HTML and PHP for ease of reading first. Also, I am not entirely convinced of the do...while loop that actually prints the result (what if the table was empty?).

Your code also contains two distinct ideas (generating the list and getting the page count), so I would break them into two separate functions. Makes code easier top read.

It may, therefore, look like this:

```
<ul>
    <?php generateList(); ?>
</ul>


<?php
function getPageCount() {
    mysql_select_db($database_connEIB, $connEIB);
    $query_rsMediaCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS med_count FROM media";
    $rsMediaCount = mysql_query($query_rsMediaCount, $connEIB) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsMediaCount = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMediaCount);

    $mCount = $row_rsMediaCount['med_count']; 
    $mPages = ceil($mCount / 2); 
}

function generateList() 
    $mIndex = 0; 
    $mPages = getPageCount();

    if ($mCount > 0) {
        for ($mPage = 1; $mPage <= $mPages; $mPage++) { 
            $result = "<li>" ;
            $query_rsMedia = "SELECT med_id FROM media LIMIT $mIndex, 2";
            $rsMedia = mysql_query($query_rsMedia, $connEIB) or die(mysql_error());
            $row_rsMedia = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMedia);
            while ((row_rsMedia = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMedia)) != null) {
                $result .= "<div>".$row_rsMedia['med_id']."</div>";
            }
            $mIndex += 2;
            $result .= "</li>
        }

        echo $result;
    }
?>
```

Hope it helps.